# Displaying records with GWT MVP

Tags: java, gwt, mvp

I am following a 'Issue tracking' gwt project with screenshots here:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mvp-sample/wiki/screenshots

This template code can show exactly one `Issue` object with the `IssueDisplayWidget`

I need to allow the app to record many `Issue`s (even just using in-memory `List<>` class for testing). And allow the `IssueDisplayWidget` to show every `Issue` added.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: @Marijn, thanks for the edit, it was very late when I wrote this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ListDataProvider](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/view/client/ListDataProvider.html) to represent data and update table after each adding with [EventBus](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/shared/EventBus.html) or directly.